# wmctrl Cannot get client list properties. (_NET_CLIENT_LIST or _WIN_CLIENT_LIST)

Tags: arch-linux, x11, wmctrl

On a fresh Arch Linux install running `ctwm`, if I do a simple `wmctrl -l`, I get

```
Cannot get client list properties. 
(_NET_CLIENT_LIST or _WIN_CLIENT_LIST)
```

I've done plenty of minimal Arch Linux installs, all basically the same, and I've never had this issue. The output is pretty vague to troubleshoot what is missing/wrong.

Comment: I removed "SOLVED" from you question's title.  Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oddly toggling the iconmanager for ctwm on and off fixed this and a few other things.